# Java script modal pop up window to open a php page within same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here,i used the below code  in order to open a php page "schd.php", when mouse right click event happens, where the schd.php page is opening as a sepearate pop window.

Where i want the schd.php page to be opened as a modal popup window within the same page(if possible with close option) , i am a newbie so please provide the answers by using the below code as example , will be veryhelpful

### CODE:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{

$(".screen").click(function() 
{ 
 });

$('.screen').bind('contextmenu', function() 
        {
     disp($(this));
         return false;
        }); 

});
function disp($this) 
{
  var source = $(".getID",$this).attr("id");

  window.open('schd.php?id='+source, 'videoplayer',   'width=350, height=550, innerHeight=550, location=no, menubar=no, status=no,  titlebar=no, scrollbars=no');
}

</script> 
</head>
<body>
```

---

Comment: are you using bootstrap??

Comment: I would advise to use bootstrap modals with iframe perhaps? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: Hi, i am not using bootstrap, can you please provide any method to use and enable the modalpoup window

Comment: Can any one help me out in this issue..